# Class diagram for variable member with the type of `std::unqiue_ptr<T>`

Tags: uml, class-diagram

```
class Foo{};

class Demo
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr{new Foo()};;
};
```

What's the relationship between `Foo` and `Demo`? I think it is composition. Am I right? How to draw such the relationship between them?

For the occasion that the variable member is not the type of `std::unique` and alike, at the association's end which tell that the class at the opposite has an attribute named after the role，e.g:
[image].

Then for the type of `std::unique<T>`, how to add the attribute?

Comment: It is an association. But as said I'm not firm with the notation for generics. So hopefully you get an answer from someone else.

Comment: @qwerty_so After I have went through many documents and posts, I still think it's composition because `class Demo` manages the lifetime of `std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr`,  when an instance of  `class Demo` is destroyed, `std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr` is destroyed, too. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, yes, it is. But in almost all cases this is irrelevant information. Who (nowadays) cares about lifetime of objects? You will use composite aggregation only for security reasons to ensure the object goes away controlled with it parent. Where else would one care about object lifetime if the garbage collector sweeps away the rubbish for you? (Well, you use C++, but that's not really an excuse ;-)

Comment: The `isOwned` dot will represent the above by making the role a attribute. Which in your thinking would be a "composition".

Comment: I'll write a partial answer...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the relation between `Demo` and `Foo` that is implemented using `std::unique_ptr` is a kind of composition:

- The `unique_ptr` ensures exclusive ownership of a `Foo` object
- The `unique_ptr` ensures control of `Foo`‘s lifecycle, i.e. as you pointed out destruction of `Demo` implies destruction of owned `Foo`.
- The fact that a `unique_ptr` can be moved is not an obstacle to the composition. On contrary, such transfers are explicitly allowed in UML.

It seems preferable to state a `0..1` multiplicity on the side of `Demo`, since your code does not require that all `Foo` instances necessarily belong to `Demo`:

[image]

I would not use the dot notation here, as I think it could mislead to think that `Demo` has a `Foo` member whereas  `Demo` has only a `unique_ptr` that implements the composition of `Foo`. You could however use an open arrow on Foo side to document that the association is navigable in that diraction (via the pointer). Although there is no other semantic in UML behind this arrow, it could elegantly and informally suggest a pointer pointing to a target.

Comment: Deriving "composition" from code is pointless. A composite aggregation is caused by some business reason. And that is not visible in the code.

Comment: @qwerty_so While I agree in general with your statement,  the C++ smart pointer `unique_ptr` are meant for representing the exact same reality as UML composition: the pointed "part object is included in at most one composite
   object at a time" (this is why it's called *unique*_ptr), and the owning object "has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed object" (destruction of owning object destroys part). In older C++ version there was just an `auto_ptr`, but C++11 has purposely differentiated unique_ptr and shared_ptr to make code more expressive about the intent.

Comment: @qwerty_so see also [here](https://books.google.be/books?id=sBwFEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=C%2B%2B+unique_ptr+UML+composition&source=bl&ots=BkpBr2QFVL&sig=ACfU3U0BKJCU2FCC98Ohwb79iP6F7ArWmg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiej6bVhar3AhXrsKQKHYcnCnUQ6AF6BAgfEAM#v=onepage&q=C%2B%2B%20unique_ptr%20UML%20composition&f=false)

Comment: @Christophe Could please draw the said class diagram for me?

Comment: @John Done. Keep in mind that dot vs arrow developed in the last paragraph is more about taste than objective argumenting:  C++ semantics with value members vs pointer members is not so easy to render in UML ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can (right now) not give an answer to the notion of generics, but I can try to clarify a few things.

Your class code shows a public attribute `foo_ptr` which is initalized with an instance of a generic class being `Foo`. This is a simple attribute and you could denote that like

[image]
(generics aside!)

There is no need to make that `foo_ptr` a composite aggregation. The latter is about object lifetime. And that should be derived from business requirements rather than from some implementation.

Composite aggregation means that the class instance is obliged to destroy the composite whenever it is terminated. So clearly some runtime implementation detail.  If, and only if, that is the case then you add a filled diamond next to `Demo`. Else you go with a simple association.

As I learned the chosen language construct ensures that explicitely. However, if you go back to abstraction you need to document the cause for composite aggregation (which can not be found in the presented code). Just adding the diamond is only half of the truth. There must be some requirement/constraint that led to this construct.

Comment: How about [this class diagram](https://ibb.co/j8NrM4s) to tell the other persons that it's a unique_ptr.

Comment: Well, you named the association which is pointless (unless you do some "magic" with UML). Please wait for someone to answer the generics-part. (I might find time later to dig into the UML specs.)

Comment: @John The naming of the association would indeed not help very much. A stereotype `<<...>>` above the association would be a cleaner option(also useless if not supported by a code generator).  Both options are misleading, because UML is not really meant for visual coding:  what if `Foo` had a `shared_ptr` back to demo?  In UML it would be a single association  navigable in both directions (arrows at both ends), despite each direction implemented in a different way in the code. There's only one name possible. You could have several stereotypes but impossible to say which one for which direction

Comment: "*But actually there is no code shown that will hold that presumption. Composite aggregation means that the class instance is obliged to destroy the composite whenever it is terminated*".  I am sorry to have to contradict you on this point.  Actually there is code: [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) ensures that the composed part is destroyed if the composite is terminated.  That's the beautiful magic and expressivity of C++11 and beyond :-)

Comment: If it were a `shared_ptr` (very similar to a Java object handle),  a `weak_ptr` or even a raw native `*`pointer,  I would however agree with you with pleasure ;-)

Comment: @Christophe My knowlege of C++ is "medium". But my point is that such an assumption should NOT come from coding but only from business although (as I was wrong here) the code supports the fact of being a composite aggregation. I make a fix to my answer.